# Python 3.8 SharedMemory performance

Tags: performance, shared-memory, python-3.8

I'm trying to use SharedMemory introduced in Python 3.8 to pass images between processes. According to my test below, writing the image to memory took around 9ms on my Ubuntu machine. I'm wondering if there are any ways to make this even faster?

```
import numpy as np
import time
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

queue_name = "queue"
image = np.zeros((2464, 2056, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
queue_size = 10
shared_memory_size = queue_size * np.prod(image.shape)
sm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=queue_name, create=True, size=shared_memory_size)
images = np.ndarray([queue_size] + list(image.shape), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=sm.buf)

t0 = time.perf_counter()
images[0] = image.data
print(time.perf_counter() - t0)
```

Comment: You are actually doing a *copy* operation, and you are actually achieving 1.6GB/s. Is there a way you could produce your data **directly** into the `images` array to avoid the copy - I mean by making the output of the previous operation write straight into `images[N]`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I also bench-marked np.copy on the same image and it takes about 2 to 3 ms. Why would shared memory copy be 3 to 4 times slower?

Comment: I don't know what OS you use, nor what CPU you have, nor what your memory architecture is, nor how many memory sticks/channels you have and I'm not sure telling me would help either